# Changing value of Select input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Html like this.

```
<input id="recommended_currency" type="hidden" value="usd"/>
<select name="currency_input">
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="eur">Euro</option>
</select>
```

And now I need Javascript to automaticaly set Select's value to value of input field above. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to do that with JavaScript? Surely you know the desired value when you create the page (since you have to populate the hidden input), so you could do it on the server (which would be more reliable and have no flash of the default default value).

Comment: @Quentin There is something that doesn't require jQuery!?!? No way...

Comment: `<option value="usd" selected>USD`. Hey look ma, no script!

Answer (score 0):

This is the straightforward answer to your question:

```
document.getElementsByName('currency_input')[0].value = 
document.getElementById('recommended_currency').value;
```

But it depends what are you really want to do. If you know the value from the server (it is not generated client-side), it's better if you set the `<select>` value from the server, too.